# php localtime() function returns UTC time instead of local time

Tags: php, date, time, localtime

in php.ini I set `date.timezone = "Europe/Amsterdam"`. Restarted Apache, the output in `phpinfo()` shows the correct timezone (Europe/Amsterdam).
Now when I print `date('H:i')` I get the UTC time, which is 2 hours behind our local time.
But when I print `localtime(time(),true)`, I still get the UTC time, while I expected the local time.

Output of `timedatectl` is:

```
Local time: Thu 2020-07-09 09:15:26 CEST
Universal time: Thu 2020-07-09 07:15:26 UTC
RTC time: Thu 2020-07-09 07:15:27
Time zone: Europe/Amsterdam (CEST, +0200)
System clock synchronized: yes
systemd-timesyncd.service active: yes
RTC in local TZ: no
```

Any help to get the local time is appreciated.

*Update:*

The output of phpinfo() is:

```
date/time support                   enabled
timelib version                     2017.09
"Olson" Timezone Database Version   0.system
Timezone Database                   internal
Default timezone                    UTC

Directive                           Local Value         Master Value
date.default_latitude               31.7667             31.7667
date.default_longitude              35.2333             35.2333
date.sunrise_zenith                 90.583333           90.583333
date.sunset_zenith                  90.583333           90.583333
date.timezone                       Europe/Amsterdam    Europe/Amsterdam
```

So "date.timezone" is correct, but what is the difference with "Default timezone?"

When I add this line above the script, the time is right:

```
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Amsterdam');
```

But the [PHP date_default_timezone_set reference page](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php) tells that "Instead of using this function to set the default timezone in your script, you can also use the INI setting date.timezone to set the default timezone.". This is what I did and doesn't work.

Setting the default timezone in the script is of course a hacky workaround; setting it in php.ini is the better way, so I'm still interested in how to fix this.

Comment: Are you sure you edited the correct php.ini file?

Comment: Yes I think so, because the result in phpinfo() shows the right timezone

Comment: I updated the question with a dump of phpinfo() and a step forward towards a solution

Comment: Maybe something/somewhere in the code/framework you use, is overwriting the setting? Are you using any framework?

Comment: Nice one! I am using Wordpress; de timezone settings in Wordpress were UTC. I changed them to Europe/Amsterdam, but no effect..

Answer (score 0):

After all I didn't find how to set this right, but added this workaround before the time-dependent code:

```
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Amsterdam');
```

Comment: I don't know if this will help, but I was having a similar issue. The server I'm using has a php.ini and a user.ini in the home directory and I had to set the date.timezone in user.ini for it to take effect.